# Unable to getWritableDatabase() - sometimes

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I regularly get reports from users with this error.

**Unable to getWritableDatabase.**

```
try {
        //dbOpenHelper is a standard SQLiteOpenHelper
        dbOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();             
} catch (Exception e) {
        //unable to connect to database.
        return;
}
```

This is only happening sometimes. What could it be? Any fixes or workarounds?

Comment: please post your logcat stack trace...

Answer (score 0):

There isn't much to go off of, need to see your LogCat to help any further. Are you closing your `dbOpenHelper`?

Here is a quick example:

```java
public DatabaseControl open() throws SQLiteException {
    dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close() {
    dbHelper.close();
}
```

---

**Edit 1** - Again, this is my best guess since a LogCat is unobtainable. *(In the end it might be in your best interest to run this application on your Dev device and try to replicate and then get your full LogCat ouput)*

It sounds to me like the Activity that has the DB is being accessed and processed fine with a proper `close()`, but in some instances maybe instead of running through that Activity the user presses the back button where `onBackPressed()` maybe should have a DB `close()` call?

In other words, to troubleshoot, I would `@Override` Acitivity lifecycle methods: `onPause()`, `onResume()`, `onStart()`, `onStop()`, and `onDestroy()` as well as `onBackPressed()` simply adding the DB `close()` and test your application then. If you do this then, I would think that, any returning lifecycle, such as `onStart()` or `onResume()` should contain the DB `getWritableDatabase()`

According to the documentation (see below), there really is no way to get `Unable to getWritableDatabase` unless the database was not closed properly. Also make sure that if you change anything in your SQlite code / structure that you need to update the DB Version #.

> **public SQLiteDatabase getWritableDatabase ()**
>
> > Create and/or open a database that will be used for reading and writing. The first time this is called, the database will be opened and onCreate(SQLiteDatabase), onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase, int, int) and/or onOpen(SQLiteDatabase) will be called.
> >
> > Once opened successfully, the database is cached, so you can call this method every time you need to write to the database. (Make sure to call close() when you no longer need the database.) Errors such as bad permissions or a full disk may cause this method to fail, but future attempts may succeed if the problem is fixed.

---

**Edit 2**

I should have shown how I called on the `open()` and `close()` methods the first time. Sorry about that. You don't need the `DatabaseHelper` open unless you are retrieving or posting to it, so immediately after processing close it until the next time you need it. Same goes for the `Cursor`, etc

Below is how I query the database, I open everything, retrieve the information, process the information and then immediately close everything. See below:

```java
DatabaseControl control = new DatabaseControl(this);

try {
    database = (new DatabaseHelper(this)).getWritableDatabase();
    DatabaseControl control = new DatabaseControl(DbTestDisplay.this);
    control.open();
    control.fetchAllItems();
    Cursor c = database.query(GlobalDBVars.TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    c.moveToFirst();

    int initialCount = c.getCount();
    Log.i("cursor", "Initial Count = " + initialCount);

    List<Integer> x = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    if (initialCount > 0) {
        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {

            /* Process everything here */

        } /* End for loop */ 
    } /* End if statement */
    control.close();
    c.close();
    database.close();
} catch (SQLException sqe) {
    Log.e("fetchAllItems", "FAILED: " + sqe.getMessage() + " allData = ");
}
```

Comment: this is happening at application start. i only open it once in the entire app.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "sometimes", when does it work, or not work? What is different? And if you want people here to help then you really need to add your LogCat / Stack Trace to your question.

Comment: I have not seen this error myself, but I get reports from users. The stacktrace doesn't show anything except this error: "Unable to get writableDatabase"

Comment: See edit above, hope you're able to figure this out. Don't know if I can provide much more help. If I think of anything else I'll come back. Let me know if you resolve. Good Luck!

Comment: this is a great answer, but the problem is i don't know where to call close() since the entire app relies on the database and as we know, application.onTerminate() is not called.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I should have showed how I called the `open()` and `close()` methods on my initial answer. See **Edit 2** above. Hope that helps.

Comment: hmm, that is not a bad idea perhaps, to open/close the database after every query..

Answer (score 0):

Try getReadableDatabase() instead of getWritableDatabase()

```
try {
        //dbOpenHelper is a standard SQLiteOpenHelper
        dbOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase();           
} catch (Exception e) {
        //unable to connect to database.
        return;
}
```